# How to join custom fields data to users table without extra rows in result set

Tags: mysql, fields, pivot

I have rudimentary knowledge of SQL (when it comes to anything but single tables) and am trying to come up with a query that will give me all the custom fields for my users.

This query will give me all my users sorted by group:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
   ->select('name, email, id')
   ->from($db->quoteName('#__users', u))
   ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__user_usergroup_map', map) . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('map.user_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id'))
   ->where('map.group_id' . ' = ' . $group)
   ->order('`name` ASC');
```

which produces:

```
SELECT name, email, id
FROM `#__users` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `#__user_usergroup_map` AS `map` ON `map`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
WHERE map.group_id = 10
ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

but I'm puzzled how to add the custom fields that are in the user context (com_users.user) and pertain to each user (based on id). Joins are something I'm just not familiar with in practice. And, Joomla's shorthand for SQL is something else I'm still puzzling through.

While I wouldn't mind just getting the pieces that would make this work, I'm also interested in the how and why - unless that's way too much for a single question.

UPDATE: having tried a few things, I find I can get all the values in the fields, but then I get repeated records - for each user, I get all the user info plus ONE field - repeated for as many fields per user as there are. What I'm wanting is ONE user with all the field data (hopefully with field names) so I can present that on a page. Here's what I tried:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('u.name, u.email, u.id, fv.value')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__users', u))
    ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__user_usergroup_map', map) . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('map.user_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id'))
    ->join('RIGHT', $db->quoteName('#__fields_values', fv) . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('fv.item_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id'))
    ->where('map.group_id' . ' = ' . $group)
    ->order('`name` ASC');
```

---

Update: 1/24 - @mickmackusa - thanks for pushing me on this.

What I did was execute a query on all the fields so I had the names. Then, I executed a query to get all the records (one field per record). Then I combined all the records into one array and passed the fields and records to the tmpl/default.php script.

Here's the queries and joining the records:

```
// let's try this: get all the field value names per category
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
        ->select('fields.title')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__fields', fields))
        ;
$db->setQuery($query, 0, 0);
$fv_list = $db->loadObjectList();
//array_unshift($fv_list, "name", "email");
//print_r($fv_list);

// now get all the fields_values
$q1 = $db->getQuery(true);
$q1
        ->select('u.name, u.email, f.title, fv.value')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__users', u))
        ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__user_usergroup_map', map) . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('map.user_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id'))
        ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__fields_values', fv) . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('fv.item_id' ) . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('u.id'))
        ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__fields',        f)  . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('fv.field_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('f.id'))
        // ->where('map.group_id' . ' = ' . $group)
        ->order('`name` ASC')
        ;
$db->setQuery($q1, 0, 0);
$fields = $db->loadObjectList();
// echo $q1 .EOL . EOL;
//print_r($fields);

foreach ($fields as $fv)
{
        $name = $fv->name;
        $list[$name][0] = $name;
        $list[$name][1] = $fv->email;
        $list[$name][$fv->title] = $fv->value;
}
return (array($fv_list, $list));
```

This produces an array of two arrays - the first is the list of field names, the second is one record per user with all the fields they've populated as key/value pairs.

In default.php, I output ALL the fields either with data the user populated or "" if the field is empty.

I'm still working on getting the data exported - but the two queries here work on Joomla 4.0.x databases, although I'm not getting group filtering like I want.

Comment: Thank you very much for joining JSE and posting a clear question that includes proof of research/toil -- I always upvote "good" questions like these.  The `#__fields_values` table typically contains multiple rows for a given "id" -- this is deliberate.  The table allows you to store multiple pieces of data for a single entity (e.g. a user's hometown, bloodtype, favorite comic book hero, etc). You are likely to need to specify an additional filter to access a particular field value or use aggregate functions.  To make your question more clear, please offer a db-fiddle and your desired result.

Comment: This answer may inspire: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/29134/12352 ...on second thought, I don't think you need a pivot query.  It is more likely that you just need to join on `field_id` AND `item_id` instead of only joining on `item_id`. And a `LEFT JOIN` will be appropriate.

Comment: what is a db-fiddle?

Comment: I included two db-fiddle demos in [this answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/29134/12352).  By building a runnable example of your exported database table(s), volunteers can test their advice without having to see up a test on their own server.

Comment: @mickmackusa - thank you for your input and guidance. It seems that subqueries were the way for me to solve the problem so I wound up getting all the field names in one query, then a second query with records for each user, one field per record. Of course, only the filled in fields per-user where returned. I then built an array of one user with ALL the records they had filled in and used that to iterate (in the oputput) printing an empty string where fields aren't filled in  and the data that existed.

Comment: Let's not abandon this posted question.  Please post what you did to resolve your question.  Perhaps I can reverse engineer a cleaner solution once I see yours.  Your question is a great opportunity to share knowledge; I want to see it through to a proper resolution.  Do you know how to export/dump your db tables and paste them into a db-fiddle? You can remove/obfuscate any private/identifiable data so that you don't breech confidentiality. Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: I haven't given up on you Josef.  I am still very prepared to help, but first I need to see some sample data from your database (it only needs to be a handful of rows from each table so that I can verify the accuracy of my advice).  I am not near my "Joomla computer", so I must wait for you to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example (mcve).  Export the targeted table data from PHPMyAdmin (or whatever RDBMS you use) and pasted it into the db-fiddle page.

Comment: Trying to get to that. My regular job is kicking my butt at the moment.

Comment: I have the four database exports randmized as csv files. However, I'm not exactly sure how to create the db_fiddle with them. Help?

Comment: I may be able to set it up for you if you create a pastebin with your data -- comment the "public" pastebin.com link.

Comment: I uploaded the files to zeevi.org/mickmackusa. There are 4 that sort of match the code above. Additionally, the INNER joins have become LEFT joins.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand your scenario, I've created [this db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nrDG5StEdHpKjhyRDHedRA/0) with your sample data and made a basic SQL query to display the JOINed data as a tabular result set.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, ugm.group_id, .f.title, fv.value
FROM lmnop_users              AS u
JOIN lmnop_user_usergroup_map AS ugm ON u.id = ugm.user_id
JOIN lmnop_fields_values      AS fv  ON u.id = fv.item_id
JOIN lmnop_fields             AS f   ON fv.field_id = f.id
WHERE ugm.group_id = {your group id}
```

Using LEFT JOINs on the `#_fields_values` and `#__fields` tables will be advisable if it is ever possible that you have users with no records in these tables AND you still want to present these users' rows.

For your dynamic pivot, you can pre-fetch all `#__fields` titles, and create a pivot query on the fly in PHP.

```
$titleQuery = $db->getQuery(true);
$titleQuery->select('title')->from('#__fields');
$db->setQuery($titleQuery);
$fieldsTitles = $db->loadColumn();
```

then

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('u.id, u.name, u.email');
foreach ($fieldsTitles as $title) {
    $query->select(
        sprintf(
            "COALESCE(MAX(IF(f.title = %s, fv.value, NULL)), '') AS %s,
            $db->q($title),
            $db->qn($title)
        )
    );
}
$query
    ->from($db->qn('#__users', 'u'))
    ->join('INNER', '#__user_usergroup_map m ON m.user_id = u.id')
    ->join('INNER', '#__fields_values     fv ON fv.item_id = u.id')
    ->join('INNER', '#__fields             f ON fv.field_id = f.id')
    ->where('m.group_id = ' . (int)$group)
    ->group('u.id, u.name, u.email')
    ->order('u.name ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
return $db->loadObjectList();
```

This should group, flatten, and coalesce all missing values to a default empty string.  Despite not actually testing the above code, I expect it to return this result -- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nrDG5StEdHpKjhyRDHedRA/1

---

If it is possible that your project will have rows in the `#__fields_values` table that doesn't relate to your users, then you'll need to filter the title fetching query.  Alternatively, there is nothing wrong with grabbing my very first (non-pivot) query, extracting all of the unique title values from the verbose result set, then iterating your result set to manually group and flatten your results and pushing default values into every new user encountered using the unique titles array.

p.s. In your PHP code, remember to wrap your table alias string in quotes so that your PHP code compiles.

Comment: @Josef how did you go with this task? It appears that you have abandoned this question.  Is your task resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I found this link: https://ubiq.co/database-blog/transpose-rows-columns-dynamically-mysql/
which helped me to create a pure MySQL solution:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
      'max(case when `f`.`name` = ''',
      `f`.`name`,
      ''' then `fv`.`value` end) `',
      `f`.`name`,
      '`'
  ) INTO @sql
FROM `#__fields` `f` 
JOIN `#__fields_groups` `fg` ON `f`.`group_id`=`fg`.`id`
WHERE `f`.`context`='com_users.user' ORDER BY `fg`.`ordering`,`f`.`ordering`;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `u`.*, ', @sql, ' 
FROM `#__users` `u`
JOIN `#__fields_values` `fv` ON `u`.`id`=`fv`.`item_id`
JOIN `#__fields` `f` ON `fv`.`field_id`=`f`.`id`
GROUP BY `u`.`id` ORDER BY `u`.`name`');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```